# How can I run a script every time windows settings change?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-runtime

I guess this can be done with the WinRT API, but how should I do that, like make an infinite loop that will check in the accent color, for example every second, and then do the function if it's not the same color as one second in the past?

Well, this is possible I guess, but is there a way to make Windows call my function automatically every time the accent color changes, for example?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the [`WM_SETTINGCHANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-settingchange) message? What "accent color" are you referring to, exactly?

Comment: You'll want to investigate how to do Windows message handling. Different languages and development libraries support this in different ways. At the lowest level, you would write a message handler which responds to the messages you choose, such as the WM_SETTINGCHANGE message that Remy mentioned. You would just register your message handler with Windows. Windows message handling is a topic quite a bit bigger than a simple Q&A in stackoverflow would cover. So you should research that topic and as a much more specific question here as needed.

Comment: The `UISettings` object has a `ColorValuesChanged` event.

Comment: @RemyLebeau like the windows accent color i wanna take that accent color values and just save it in some way to use it in another app
but a while loop seems overkill that's why I asked thanks

Comment: it's like i wanna say to windows run this .exe file if by any means the accent color changes like when windows after running the function that changes the accent color I wanna him to automatically run my .exe somehow

Comment: @BeheKH "*like the windows accent color*" - and where are you changing that color value, exactly?  Is that a setting in the Windows Control Panel? A property of an object in your code? Or something else?  You need to be more specific. "*when windows after running the function that changes the accent color I wanna him to automatically run my .exe somehow*" - sorry, but that is not how Windows works.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i'm talking about the general accent color in windows in settings personalisation colors

well I guess then the only option is to make a while loop checking if the accent color actually changes thanks

Comment: @BeheKH Are you talking about Windows' Display Personalization settings? If so, then those are global settings, and so will broadcast a `WM_SETTINGCHANGED` message when changed. At program startup, grab the current accent color as needed, such as from `GetSysColor()`. Then setup a window procedure to handle `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` messages, and when received then retrieve the current accent color again and see if it has changed, and if so then act accordingly.

Comment: thanks a lot well i'll do this thanks